# Vue variable value not updating after a request

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

Hi everyone I'm having trouble about variable value.

Inside the request I'm matching each array values if their is a match then update the **match** variable to true if their is. The problem is that the returned **match** variable is not updating outside the request after it gets updated inside the request. How am I able to get the updated **match** value?

**Template**

```
<template>
   <div>{{$acl(['post.edit'])}}</div> <!-- always display false -->
</template>
```

**Nuxt plugin**

```
let match = false
let moduleName = ''
let actionName = ''

Vue.prototype.$acl = ( access ) => {

    let bindAccess = access

    storeRequest.then( done => {
        _.each( bindAccess, ( value, index ) => {
            moduleName = value.split('.')[0]
            actionName = value.split('.')[1]

            /**
             * check if user access modules match with bindAccess module
             */
            if( aclConfig[moduleName] != undefined ) {
                _.each( aclConfig[moduleName], ( actions, index ) => {
                    if(actions.action_name === actionName) {
                        match = true
                        return false
                    }
                })
            }
        })

        console.log(match) //returns true since their is a match
    })

    console.log(match) //always returns false
    return match
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The promise get resolved **after** the method returns so `match` is changed after the method returns, hence you'll always get false.

You should declare a field on the component instance and then change that var from inside the plugin.

```
<template>
 <div>{{$acl(['post.edit']), isAMatch}}</div>
</template>
```

and in the plugin

```
Vue.prototype.$acl = ( access ) => {

 let bindAccess = access

 storeRequest.then( done => {
    _.each( bindAccess, ( value, index ) => {
        moduleName = value.split('.')[0]
        actionName = value.split('.')[1]

        /**
         * check if user access modules match with bindAccess module
         */
        if( aclConfig[moduleName] != undefined ) {
            _.each( aclConfig[moduleName], ( actions, index ) => {
                if(actions.action_name === actionName) {
                    this.isAMatch = true
                    return false
                }
            })
        }
    })
 })

 // no need to return here
 // return match
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use mixins, like this:

```
{
  data: () => {
    return { 
       aclConfig
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.aclConfig = this.$store.getAclConfig(); // or maybe using Promise
  },
  methods: {
    checkAccess(roles) {
       let match = false;
       _.each(roles, (role) => {
         const splited = value.split('.');
         const moduleName = splited[0];
         const actionName = splited[1];
         if (this.aclConfig[moduleName]) {
            _.each(this.aclConfig[moduleName], (actions) => {
              if (actions.action_name === actionName) {
                match = true;
                return false;
              }
           });
        }
      });

      return match;
    }
  }
}
```

And you can use this in template like this:

```
<template>
 <div>{{ checkAccess(['post.edit']) }}</div>
</template>
```